# Singleton pattern based on parameter to create promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, singleton, es6-promise

I am trying to use a singleton pattern to prevent repeated network requests with same parameters.

I am creating a Promise for making an API call

If the parameter is same the same promise is returned else a new promise is created

I am storing the parameter locally inside the singleton to detect change in parameter

Below is my code

```
var getData = (()=>{
  var prev_param; //is this the correct way to store previous parameter locally
  var promise_instance;
  createInstance = (param)=>{
    prev_param = param;
    const temp_promise = this.props.dispatch(actions.getData(param)).then(getDataResult=>{
      this.setState({result: getDataResult});
    });
    return temp_promise;
  }

  return (param)=>{
    if (param && prev_param !== param) {
      promise_instance = createInstance(param);
    }
    return promise_instance;
  };
})();
getData("param1");
getData("param1");
getData("param2");
getData("param2");
```

is it right to store previous param like this

is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be alot easier to just use proper caching so requests with the same parameters get loaded from cache when requested again? Then you don't have to bother with this yourself. I guess it could affect rendering speeds, but since you use react, I'm not even sure yet if it will actually update state and rerender.

Comment: I am not aware how to implement caching, if you could give me a lead?
I am doing a forceUpdate in `getData("param1").then(()=>this.forceUpdate());`

Comment: It's settings in the web server and whatever services you use to get data, not something we code on the frontend. Ask your network admins for more information about how caching works in your business and how you can make it help your website.

Answer (score 2):

That is a pretty standard approach for memoization. I am not certain on your needs but I *think* you might want to use an object or map for storing the previous calls (unless you want to store the last call only). So something like

```
const getData = (()=>{
    let prevParams = {}; //is this the correct way to store previous parameter locally

    const createInstance = param => {
        prevParams[param] = this.props.dispatch(actions.getData(param)).then(getDataResult=>{
            this.setState({result: getDataResult});
        });
        return prevParams[param];
    }

    return param => {
        return param && prevParams[param] || createInstance(param);
    };
})();

getData("param1");
getData("param1");
getData("param2");
getData("param2");
```

The issue here is that this.props will probably not exist in the context but I am presuming this code has been taken out of the context where it will be called. Furthermore, this.setState will not get called every time - only the first time that the parameter is used. Successive calls with the same parameter will be passed the resolved promise chain. If you want the setState to be called every time you call the function, even with the same param then you would probably want to move the then statement -see below

```
const getData = (()=>{
    let prevParams = {}; //is this the correct way to store previous parameter locally

    const createInstance = param => {
        prevParams[param] = this.props.dispatch(actions.getData(param));
        return prevParams[param];
    }

    return param => {
        return (param && prevParams[param] || createInstance(param))
            .then(getDataResult=>{
                this.setState({result: getDataResult});
            });
    };
})();

getData("param1");
getData("param1");
getData("param2");
getData("param2");
```

I've made a lo of assumptions about the code so sorry if any are wrong :)